# How can I plot hollowed symbols connected with dotted lines in one go?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot hollowed symbols connected with dotted lines using matplotlib.  If I do

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o:', fillstyle='none')
```

the symbols become dotted also.  I could plot them separately to get symbols with solid boundary

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', fillstyle='none')
plt.plot(x, y, ':')
```

but I then mess up my legends, since this cannot make both the symbol and the line into one single legend entry.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to post this as an answer - I can't include images in comments...

Are you sure the symbol is dotted? This program (I've enlarged the symbols a bit):

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def test_plot():
    x = range(11)
    y = [x0**2 for x0 in x]

    plt.plot(x, y, 'o:', fillstyle='none', label = "1", ms = 10)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def main(args):
    test_plot()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Shows solid symbols, and dotted lines:

[image]

which seems the logical way to do it. Note that the joining lines start at the center of the first symbol of the segment, and stops before the last symbol. If you want to 'clean' the complete symbol, you can either fill with white as proposed by Replikis's answer

FEEDBACK FROM MATPLOTLIB mailing list:

From Ben Root:

> We have been recently fixing a bunch of issues in the macosx backend
>   (which is default on Macs). Having the circle be dotted sounds exactly
>   like the sort of problem that would be caused by some of the bugs we
>   are addressing. I think we have some of the fixes committed to the
>   master branch, so if you could build and install from git, you can see
>   if the problem is fixed yet or not.

From Thomas Caswell:

> The PR to fix this is still open:
>   https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4202

Comment: Weird.  It looks like this behavior is platform dependent.  I tried your script on both my macbook pro and my linux mint desktop.  The latter shows the same result, but I still get dotted symbols on my mac.  I am using Anaconda  2.3.0 on my mac, which has matplotlib 1.4.3, and I am using matplotlib 1.3.1 on my linux desktop.  I am using python3.4 in both cases.  Any idea what is wrong (or right) with my mac?

Comment: Here, I'm using version matplotlib is 1.3.1. I've just downloaded 1.4.3, and I'll try it out later and report back. One large difference between 1.3 and 1.4, is the new Style package. Maybe adding the package caused this difference. I have also looked over the bug tracker at nabble.com, the issue tracker on sourceforge, and the 1.4 Changelog, but I did not find any notes on the subject

Comment: Wow, this took some doing. I installed matplotlib 1.4.3 now, and plotting stopped working altogether! Only till I changed the Agg to GtkAgg did plotting work again. But no difference from 1.3.1 - I'd do a screen grab, but it would be identical to the above.

Comment: OK.  I tried different backends on my mac.  Although I don't have GTK installed, the backends 'TkAgg' and 'Qt4Agg' do work correctly.  And it is the backend 'MacOSX' gives the dotted symbol problem.  Which part is responsible for this bug?  Anaconda?  Mac OS?  Or something else?

Comment: I've sent a mail to the Matplotlib mailing list with your issue, and another one with mine. I believe this is the normal course of action with matplotlib issues. If the problem is minor, it might get solved rapidly, else I'll escalate them to the bug tracker. I'll report if I get any response.

Comment: I already received several replies to the post in the mailing list, and I've added them to the Answer above. Seems the MacOSX backend is still actively being worked on.

Comment: Thanks for taking this up to matplotlib and getting the answers.  I'll mark this question as answered.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I've just 'escalated' the issue to the tracker on Sourceforge. I have also a report that it could be solved in the latest development version. If you feel up to it, you could download the latest version from the git repo, and compile it yourself. It's not that difficult once you have all dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a white fill to the markers, instead of no fill. This can be done with:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o:', markerfacecolor='w')
```

If you use a different plot background colour, you can change 'w' (for white) to the colour you want.

Comment: Since this seems to have done nothing more than extend another answer, it should perhaps have been added as a comment to the other answer.

Comment: @JasonD Since this one was posted before the other answer, your comment is invalid. You really should stop commenting under my old posts just to get to me.

Comment: @Repiklis Sorry, simple mistake.  And why would that "get to you"?